# Cucumber Upgrade JVM > 7.10.1 - NoSuchMethodError java.util.stream.Stream io.cucumber.gherkin.GherkinParser.parse

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

We are using cucumber with JAVA, pico container and testNG runner. I am trying to upgrade cucumber binaries from 7.4.1 to 7.10.1 or above. However looks like the class io.cucumber.gherkin.GherkinParser doesn't have the method parse. I am not calling this method directly but via testNG runner like below:

```
testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
```

At this point i get the parse error :

com.aaa.automation.runner.CucumberRunner.setUpClassorg.testng.TestRunner@4a9ca899  Time elapsed: 5.957 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Stream io.cucumber.gherkin.GherkinParser.parse(java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream)'
at com.aaa.automation.runner.CucumberRunner.setUpClass(CucumberRunner.java:254)

Any insight on this is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like your dependencies don't converge. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje mvn dependency:tree gives me build success , I am not familiar with this particular command but i believe i dont see any issue here.

Comment: Did you look at the output of the command? And you could read its documentation.

Comment: I couldn't see any issue in the output